# Building a central service for internationalization in asp net core 7 in microservice architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, microservices

I want to create a service to translate different languages of application UI, I want to develop this service with aspnetcore 7 framework.

The way I'm considering is to create a service called "Translator" that will create a hub for the rest of the services, which they can use to translate their sentences.

The implementation method that I have in mind is to use resx files and put the sentences in it, then through the api of other servers, they give key and culture and get the value.

Considering that in the future, services with different frameworks and languages may be developed, and it is also possible that the microservice architecture may be next to a microfrontend architecture(Each microservice provides its user interface in the form of a razorlibrary or razorcomponent for the main project, which is Blazor. ), and according to the definition "Internationalization (I18N): Both globalization and localization." Is it correct in the way I have in mind?
Is it possible to centralize globalization and localization (currently all projects are going to be implemented with aspnetcore)?

Is there a suitable tool for this? Because the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0) I saw from the Microsoft site doesn't seem to be suitable for this solution (or I have little knowledge about it).
I would be grateful if you could give me a clear guide.